# How to find out when a service was restarted using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I have a Powershell script as below using which i want to find out the uptime of a service.

This script is able to successfully capture the uptime of service if there is a reboot of the machine itself or stop/start of the service.

But when the service is stopped, it doesn't capture the correct time since when it was stopped and still i'm getting the uptime as since when the machine was rebooted.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

```
function Get-ServiceUptime
{
  param([string]$Name)

  # Prepare name filter for WQL
  $Name = $Name -replace "\\","\\" -replace "'","\'" -replace "\*","%"

  # Fetch service instance
  $Service = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE '$Name'"

  # Use ProcessId to fetch corresponding process
  $Process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($Service.ProcessId)"

  # Calculate uptime and return
  return (Get-Date) - $Process.CreationDate
}

$uptime = Get-ServiceUptime -Name MyServiceName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows events to find out when the service was started. Service itself doesnt keep track of when it was restarted...

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "Service Control Manager" -EntryType "Information" -Message "*Print Spooler service*running*" -Newest 1).TimeGenerated
```

This will not tell you whether the service is still running or not but last time it was up. You'll need to check for events that show when it was stopped and compare the dates to see if its still running and when it last came up.

Also note that the windows logs rotate and because of that some services that have been running longer than the oldest record will not be available.

*above example taken from [here](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/service-start-time/)*

Comment: I even tried this but this doesn't seem to work for the service (Apache) that i'm interested in. I couldn't debug/find the root cause though.

Comment: I would check and see if a GPO or other policies are in place that doesnt record audit for service start stop